# SQL Server: aggregate counts grouped by user based on csv values in a text field

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure how best to describe my problem in words without before/after examples, which is probably why I can't find an existing solution here.

I have 'tags' in a user defined field in our tickets database to represent errors made when handling said ticket. The field could be empty, could have one entry, or multiple entries. They *should* be comma separated, but I have no ability to validate text as it's being entered. The temporary table #Categories below shows the current 'tags' I expect to appear in this field.

I can get my desired results with the approach below, but I feel like this is clumsy and there's almost certainly a more elegant solution that doesn't require running the same update command over and over with a manual change of the Category it's matching on. This also will require manual updating if a new 'tag' is introduced (or if somebody typo's a tag and thus doesn't result in a match).

My desired results are a list of users, with a count of 'errors', i.e. the occurrences of those tags across all the user defined fields of all tickets within the date range specified (including 0), like shown below. The ideal solution would inherently include new users & new categories (tags) without manual intervention so I'd see them on the resultant report this will be used for.

| User | Category | Errors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jdoe | Board | 0 |
| jdoe | Budget | 1 |
| jdoe | Conflict | 0 |
| jdoe | Contact | 2 |
| jdoe | Dupe | 1 |
| jdoe | Item | 0 |
| jdoe | SkipDispatch | 0 |
| jdoe | SLAMiss | 0 |
| jdoe | SubType | 5 |
| jdoe | Type | 0 |
| jdoe | whitespace | 0 |
| jsmith | Board | 0 |
| jsmith | Budget | 0 |
| jsmith | Conflict | 1 |
| jsmith | Contact | 0 |
| jsmith | Dupe | 0 |
| jsmith | Item | 2 |
| jsmith | SkipDispatch | 0 |
| jsmith | SLAMiss | 0 |
| jsmith | SubType | 0 |
| jsmith | Type | 0 |
| jsmith | whitespace | 1 |

```
-- I want to include all users and all category combinations, so I build a table
-- with those combinations first to ensure NULL entries are still represented (as zero)

CREATE TABLE #Categories (Category varchar(30))

INSERT INTO #Categories (Category)
VALUES ('Agreement')
        ,('Board')
        ,('Budget')
        ,('Conflict')
        ,('Contact')
        ,('Dupe')
        ,('Item')
        ,('SkipDispatch')
        ,('SLAMiss')
        ,('Subtype')
        ,('Type')
        ,('Whitespace')

CREATE TABLE #Errors 
(
    User varchar(50), 
    Category varchar(30), 
    Errors Int
)

INSERT INTO #Errors (User, Category, Errors)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        A.User, D.Category, 0
    FROM
        Tickets_SLA_Workflow A
    LEFT JOIN
        Tickets C ON A.Tickets_RecID = C.Tickets_RecID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Tickets_User_Defined_Field_Value B ON C.Tickets_RecID = B.Tickets_RecID
    CROSS JOIN 
        #Categories D
    WHERE
        B.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 28
        AND A.Date_Responded BETWEEN @Start AND @End

-- Next I update that table with the actual counts of occurrences of the tag "Board"

UPDATE #Errors
SET Errors = Board.Errors
FROM #Errors A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT A.User, COUNT(B.User_Defined_Field_Value) Errors
     FROM Tickets_SLA_Workflow A
     LEFT JOIN Tickets C ON A.Tickets_RecID = C.Tickets_RecID
     LEFT JOIN Tickets_User_Defined_Field_Value B ON C.Tickets_RecID = B.Tickets_RecID
     WHERE B.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 28
       AND A.Date_Responded_UTC BETWEEN @Start AND @End
       AND B.User_Defined_Field_Value LIKE '%Board%'
     GROUP BY A.User) Board on A.User = Board.User
WHERE
    A.Category = 'Board'
    AND A.User = Board.User

-- Then I repeat for tag "Budget" ... and so on through all the categories

UPDATE #Errors
SET Errors = Budget.Errors
FROM #Errors A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT A.User, COUNT(B.User_Defined_Field_Value) Errors
     FROM Tickets_SLA_Workflow A
     LEFT JOIN Tickets C ON A.Tickets_RecID = C.Tickets_RecID
     LEFT JOIN Tickets_User_Defined_Field_Value B ON C.Tickets_RecID = B.Tickets_RecID
     WHERE B.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 28
       AND A.Date_Responded_UTC BETWEEN @Start AND @End
       AND B.User_Defined_Field_Value LIKE '%Budget%'
     GROUP BY A.User) Budget ON A.User = Budget .User
WHERE
    A.Category = 'Budget'
    AND A.User = Budget.User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is denormalized, as each category should really be in a separate row. But we can transform it by splitting the categories by commas using `STRING_SPLIT`.

You can then simply aggregate by user and category.

```sql
SELECT
  wf.[User],
  s.value AS Category,
  COUNT(*) Errors
FROM Tickets_SLA_Workflow wf
JOIN Tickets t ON wf.Tickets_RecID = t.Tickets_RecID
JOIN Tickets_User_Defined_Field_Value fv
  ON t.Tickets_RecID = fv.Tickets_RecID
    AND fv.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 28
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (fv.User_Defined_Field_Value, ',') s
WHERE wf.Date_Responded_UTC BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY
  wf.User,
  s.value;
```

If not all the catgories are correctly separated by commas, but you have an actual list of categories, then you could get almost the same result by using `LIKE`. The downside is that overlapping categories (such as `Contact` and `Contacts`) will return twice.

```sql
SELECT
  wf.[User],
  c.Category,
  COUNT(*) Errors
FROM Tickets_SLA_Workflow wf
JOIN Tickets t ON wf.Tickets_RecID = t.Tickets_RecID
JOIN Tickets_User_Defined_Field_Value fv
  ON t.Tickets_RecID = fv.Tickets_RecID
    AND fv.User_Defined_Field_RecID = 28
JOIN Categories c ON fv.User_Defined_Field_Value LIKE '%' + c.Category + '%'
WHERE wf.Date_Responded_UTC BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY
  wf.User,
  c.Category;
```

> Note: [avoid using meaningless aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) such as `A` and `B`

> Note: `LEFT JOIN` followed by `WHERE` on that table becomes an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I'm looking for and MUCH simpler. The only piece I'm still missing is that I want to include ALL categories for ALL users, with zero where there's no matches.

Comment: Change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`. Like I said, you should really have a list of categories, then you can place it at the beginning, and `LEFT JOIN` everything else to it